# Specify command-line C++ version for cl.exe (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cl

I'm testing the C++17 [fallthrough](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough) attribute in Visual Studio Code. The IDE has been configured to compile C/C++ code using the Microsoft Visual Studio cl.exe compiler. My task definition (in `tasks.json`) to build a simple `.cpp` file in DEBUG mode is:

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "cl.exe: Build active file",
    "command": "cl.exe",
    "args": [
        "/Zi",
        "/EHsc",
        "/Fe:",
        "${file}",
        "/link",
        "/OUT:${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
    ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$msCompile"
    ]
}
```

This has been tested on several programs and works well. Now I include a `switch` statement using the new `[[fallthrough]];` attribute and the compiler generates:

```
warning C5051: attribute 'fallthrough' requires at least '/std:c++17'; ignored
```

Adding `"/std:c++17",` to the "args" for cl.exe changed nothing (the same compiler warning is generated). Here is the new version:

```
"args": [
    "/Zi",
    "/EHsc",
    "/Fe:",
    "/std:c++17",
    "${file}",
    "/link",
    "/OUT:${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
],
```

As far as I can see, my syntax is correct according to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version) for specifying the language standard.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc you can check this link

Comment: If you want more control over the C/C++ extension, you can create a c_cpp_properties.json file, which will allow you to change settings such as the path to the compiler, include paths, C++ standard (default is C++17), and more.

Comment: Ah, good tip! Do you mean with the `"compilerArgs"` parameter in `c_cpp_properties.json`?

Comment: you can prefer the above link for example.

Comment: Hmm, have added `"cppStandard": "c++17"` to the `\.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json` file, but still get the same `requires c++17 ...ignored` warning. The syntax is rather fiddly!

Comment: I've noticed that if I add the full path to `cl.exe` in the `"includePath"` parameter of `c_cpp_properties.json` and DO NOT run the `Visual Studio Command Prompt`, that the compile fails with `'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I think my `c_cpp_properties.json` is not being picked up or applied, and I don't understand why.

Comment: That reference to fallthrough is already linked to in the question. The code itself is not relevant to the question (it is, in fact, exactly the code in that reference)...any C++17 feature will generate the same warning.

Comment: Why are you worrying about a `.json` file? If you are using the *VS Developers Command Prompt* (either with `cmd.exe` or `PowerShell`), simply compile your program, e.g. `cl /Zi /EHsc /FeYourExeName /std:c++17 YourSource.cpp` (you should add `/W3` to enable full-warnings. You can add `/Fo...` to specify the object file name if desired. The point being, if you are compiling from the command line, no `.json` file is necessary. A simple `.bat` file can handle your filename, objectname and exename arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this issue while searching for something else, but here's a fix for you :).

Your problem is the order in which you supply the arguments. `/Fe:` is expecting the file path straight after - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fe-name-exe-file?view=msvc-160

Here's an example `args` section taken from the VSCode [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) but I've added the `/std:c++17` compiler flag

```
"args": [
    "/Zi",
    "/EHsc",
    "/std:c++17", // <= put your compiler flag here
    "/Fe:", // <= /Fe: followed by the path + filename
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "${file}"
]
```

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: I now put the `std:c++17` as the first argument in all my `tasks.json` files for C++ and this works.